# Is there a way to make a search bar on discord.py?

Tags: discord, discord.py

I recently made a discord bot that webscrapes through a specific website and searches for what the user specifies but the problem is that people spell things wrong and it the bot can't find what they're looking for. One way I thought to fix this is to make a sort of search bar, for example it shows results as they type in like any search engine search bar. Is there anyway to do this or are there any other solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using an [`autocomplete`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html?highlight=autocomplete#discord.app_commands.autocomplete) in a slash command.

Comment: The issue with that is the max is 25 but there is 2000 results needed...

Comment: @James_Hawkes you can't possibly expect anyone to scroll through 2000 items. Discord caps you off at 25, nothing you can do about it. In your autocomplete, filter down your list based on their current search query & then just use basic list slicing to get the first 25 out.

Comment: Sorry for having little knowledge but is it possible to filter down that much on a list and if so how?

Comment: Filtering can be done with either a list comprehension or the `filter` function, you can Google around for both